# Problems with execution aws command via ssh jenkins

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, ssh

Good morning, how are you?

I have a problem with one execution via ssh in my jenkins.

[image: Jenkins problem]

Those characters that appear before did not appear, and we have not changed anything in the node..

The code we use is:

```
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'id', passwordVariable: 'pass', usernameVariable: 'user')]) {
        
                                def remote = [:]
                                remote.name = 'id_nme'
                                remote.host = 'ip_node'
                                remote.user = user
                                remote.password = pass
                                remote.allowAnyHosts = true
                                remote.timeoutSec = 300
        
        sshCommand remote: remote, command: "aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name [name_asg]"

}
```

When the command is launched, the job is stuck and does not progress.